# Как решить проблему в обход kill -9?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

kill -9 не помогает. Чем завершить данный процесс

Comment: А у вас тем устройством, файл на котором удаляет этот rm  все в порядке ? Видно, что процесс ожидает операции ввода-вывода, пока устройство не выполнит его запрос (или не вернет ему ошибку) завершить его невозможно

Comment: Перезагрузкой?.

Comment: @Mike Файлы и коннект к папке сетевой восстановил. Но пока прояснения нет

Comment: ну и оставьте его в покое. может как нибудь сам отвалится. больше вы с ним ничего не сделаете

Comment: @Mike процессорное время ест. Перезагружать не могу. Продакшен

Comment: Процессорное время он вообще не потребляет. Он считается активным так как ожидает ввода-вывода. При ожидании ввода-вывода процессу ядро не передаст управление, пока ввод-вывод не произойдет. Как только это произойдет он завершится, так как вы давали ему 9 сигнал

Comment: а это отдельный процесс или команда из скрипта?
если из скрипта - то можно попробовать убить родительский процесс. и посмотрите какие файлы он держит командой lsof -p PID . меняется ли список файлов? как вариант попытаться удалить эти файлы по одному или небольшими пачками.